# Having trouble with Pandas groupby statement find ranges

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I am using the link ([Python - calculating the range(highest - lowest) in different group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560578/python-calculating-the-rangehighest-lowest-in-different-group)) as guide for calculating different ranges for different groups. However, I am running into SyntaxError: invalid syntax error when I run my code, and I cannot figure out the reason.

Here is a sample dataset that I am using and the code that is giving me the error

```
  Date       Group   Away Moneyline  Away Pointspread Points 
Sun Sep 1      A         10              4      
Mon Sep 2      B         NaN             6
Tue Sep 3      A         20              10
Wed Sep 4      C         39              4



range = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x."Away Pointspread points".max() - x."Away Pointspread points".min()
```

The output of the code is SyntaxError: invalid syntax. What I am expecting is the range for the observations in Group. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `x."Away Pointspread points".max()` seems wrong syntax to me

Comment: Also, next time try to provide the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part: `x."Away Pointspread points"` is incorrect. Try using `x["Away Pointspread points"]` instead.

That would be:

```py
range = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x["Away Pointspread points"].max() - x["Away Pointspread points"].min()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use brackets when columns names have spaces, other special chars or use reserved words ('print', for example).
Also, the column name is `Away Pointspread Points` (capital P in points).
Should look something like:

```
df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x["Away Pointspread Points"].max() - x["Away Pointspread Points"].min())
```