# Calculating the range of values in a Pandas DataFrame using groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset which has feature 'abdomcirc' that has multiple values per ChildID, like so:

```
    ChildID     abdomcirc
0   1           273
1   1           267
2   1           294
3   2           136
4   2           248
```

I want to calculate the range of values for a given a list of abdomcirc values per child id. So I want to get these results:

```
    ChildID     range
0   1           27
1   2           112
```

So I first tried this:

```py
df["range"] = df.groupby('ChildID')["mussabdomcirc"].transform('range')
```

But I got this error **ValueError: 'range' is not a valid function name for transform(name)**

So, as suggested in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560578/python-calculating-the-rangehighest-lowest-in-different-group), I tried the following line:

```py
df["range"] = df.groupby('ChildID').apply(lambda x: x.High.max() - x.Low.min())
```

But I got this error:
**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'High'**

Not sure why I am getting this error. Any suggestion on how to successfully calculate the range of a group of values in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`High` is not in `df`, please change `High` with your column

```
df.groupby("ChildID").apply(lambda x: x['abdomcirc'].max() - x['abdomcirc'].min())
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I am trying to rename the column 'abdomcirc' to 'range' but it is not working, I am just getting a column name (0).

I am running this command:


df.groupby('ChildID').apply(
    lambda x: x.abdomcirc.max() - x.abdomcirc.min()).reset_index().rename(
    columns={"abdomcirc": "range"})

Comment: That worked, thanks! Any idea why it is automatically renaming the column to 0? I didn't face this problem before when using groupby and lambda function.

Comment: I think better way is `.reset_index(name='range')`

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I get the error: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Answer (score 2):

There is one function from `numpy.ptp`

```
s=df.groupby('ChildID')['abdomcirc'].apply(np.ptp).to_frame('range').reset_index()
Out[75]: 
   ChildID  range
0        1     27
1        2    112
```

Fix your code

```
df.groupby('ChildID').apply(lambda x: x.abdomcirc.max() - x.abdomcirc.min())
```